# How to pause a python script to execute further but the subprocess must run for specified time

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen("exec " +runcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            while p.poll() == None:
            #while True:
                    output = p.stdout.readline()
                    print (output)
                    if output == '' and p.poll is not None:
                            break
                    if output:
                            str = output.strip()
                            if '"Activate"' in str:
                                    print ("pause initiated")
```

Here when stdout/ouput finds the Activate in the log I want to pause script but the subprocess execution must continue for that specified time?? Please help and correct me if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: I don't fully understand. You want to pause (=suspend) the `exec runcmd` and continue in your python script? And after some time you want to continue the script until it has finished? Is that correct?

Comment: I want to exec runcmd to continue to run...when its find the "Activate" in the stdout...I want to suspend the while loop and subprocess continue to run in that suspended period. once that suspended period over...immediately I want to kill the suprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what you're looking for but the following script:

1. starts runcmd (you don't need `exec` before the command)
2. waits until it finds `"Activate"` in its output (or stops when the program ends before, that's already correct with the `.poll()` calls)
3. sleeps for 10s
4. kills the process and breaks the loop

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(runcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    while p.poll() == None:
        output = p.stdout.readline()
        print (output)
        if output == '' and p.poll is not None:
            break
        if output:
            s = output.strip()
            if '"Activate"' in s:
                print ("pause initiated")
                time.sleep(10) # wait 10 seconds
                return_value = p.kill()
                break # explicit break, this is not needed as p.poll() would return -9
```